# How can I define custom quarter boundaries (not calendar) in R?

Tags: r

I see a ton of libraries like zoo, ts, timeSeries for working with quarters but I can't seem to figure out a way to change quarter boundaries.
The data I analyze needs to be broken into fiscal quarters.

Ex:
Fiscal Q1: 7/28/2013 - 10/26/2013
Fiscal Q2: 10/27/2013 - 1/25/2014
and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try useing `cut` to define your own date ranges:

```
boundaries <- as.Date(c("7/28/2013","10/27/2013","1/26/2014"),"%m/%d/%Y")
quarterNames <- c("Fiscal Q1","Fiscal Q2")
cut(vectorOfDates ,
    breaks = boundaries,
    labels = quarterNames)
```

Note that you need one more boundary than label (since the labels are applied to the ranges between the `breaks`), and that the boundaries must span your date range, otherwise you'll introduce missing values.

Comment: This is great... it will take me a couple of days to digest what's really going on but it definitely did the trick. Thank you very much for the super fast reply